# laravel 5.4 use where in blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5

what is the correct syntax to write this code in laravel 5.4

```
@foreach($productChuck as $product where $product->category_id = 1)
```

//some date this section
@endforeach

all I want is display only those product that has category_id of 1

thanks in advance

Comment: please show what you have done so far

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
@foreach($productChuck->where('category_id', 1) as $product)
    ....
@endforeach
```

Assuming `$productChuck` is a collection. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where) for more information.

Comment: It's work! that is what I want to be, thanks a lot Aaron Fahey you save me God bless

Comment: You're missing your closing `)` -> `@foreach ($productChuck->where('category_id', 1) as $product)`